# What is French translation of English 'ready meal'?

Tags: alimentation

So in England the supermarkets have [plenty of 'ready meals'](https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/chilled-/all-ready-meals-44) which one puts in microwave or a hot oven.   If I put ready meal into Google Translate I get 'Repas prêts' but I think 'Plats cuisinés' is closer.

However, if I look at search results for 'Plats cuisinés' some of them are canned and some boxed whereas the English ready-meal is typically found in a refrigerated section, and is laid out in a plastic tray with a cardboard sleeve.  One removes the sleeve and perforates the film and places in microwave.

Often they are Indian, Thai or Chinese meals, i.e. ethnic cuisine.

I was just wondering if I was missing a better translation or do the French cook far more from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though ***plats cuisinés*** can be used, ***plats préparés*** is more common, and closer to the literal translation ;)

Comment: ***Prêts-à-manger*** too, à la ***prêt-à-porter***.

Comment: Excellent, 'plats préparés' got me to  https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/categorie/plats-prepares